# Python Regex Error--returns either Nonetype or wrong part of string

Tags: python, regex

I couldn't quite find a similar question on here (or don't know Python well enough to figure it out from other questions), so here goes.

I'm trying to extract part of a string with re.search().start (I've also tried end()), and that line either seems to find something (but a few spaces off) or it returns None, which is baffling me. For example:

```
def getlsuscore(line):
print(line)
start=re.search(' - [0-9]', line).start()+2
score=line[start:start+3]
print(score)
score=int(score.strip())
return(score)
```

The two prints are in there for troubleshooting purposes. The first one prints out:
02:24   LSU     62 - 80 EDDLESTONE,BRANDON SUB IN. SHORTESS,HENRY SUB IN. ROBINSON III,ELBERT SUB OUT. QUARTERMAN,TIM SUB OUT.

Exactly as I expect it to. For the record, I'm trying to extract the 80 in that line and force it to an int. I've tried with various things in the regex match, always including the hyphen, and accordingly different numbers at the end to get me to the correct starting point, and I've tried playing with this in many other ways and still haven't got it to work. As for the print(score), I either get "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'" when I have the start()+whatever correct, or if I change it to something wrong just to try it out, I get something like "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'" or "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '- 8'", with no addition or +1, respectively. So why when I put +2 or +3 at the end of start() does it give me an error? What am I messing up here?

Thanks for the help, I'm a noob at Python so if there's another/better way to do this that isn't regex, that works as well. I've just been using this exact same thing quite a bit on this project and had no problems, so I'm a bit stumped.

Edit: More code/context

```
def getprevlsuscore(file, time):
realline=''
for line in file:
    line=line.rstrip()
    if line[0:4]==time:
        break
    if re.search('SUB IN', line):
        if not re.search('LSU', line[:9]):
            realline=line
return(getlsuscore(realline))
```

It only throws the error when called in this block of code, and it's reading from a text file that has the play by play of a basketball game. Several hundred lines long, formatted like the line above, and it only throws an error towards the end of the file (I've tried on a couple different games).

The above function is called by this one:

```
def plusminus(file, list):
    for player in list:
    for line in file:
        line=line.rstrip()
        if not re.search('SUB IN', line):
            continue
        if not re.search('LSU', line):
            continue
        if not re.search(player.name, line):
            continue
        lsuscore=getlsuscore(line)
        previouslsuscore=getprevlsuscore(file, line[0:4])
        oppscore=getoppscore(line)
        previousoppscore=getprevoppscore(file, line[0:4])
    print(lsuscore)
    print(previouslsuscore)
    print(oppscore)
    print(previousoppscore)
```

Obviously not finished, the prints are to check the numbers. The scope of the project is that I'm trying to read a txt file copy/paste of a play by play and create a plus/minus for each player, showing the point differentials for the time they've played (e.g. if player X was in for 5 minutes, and his school scored 15 while the other school scored 5 in that time, he'd be +10).

Comment: Python has so many simpler ways of dealing with strings - regex is almost never the best way.

Comment: I stand by Regex being the wrong way of doing things. Better than `re.search()`, just use `in`. Example: `if 'SUB IN' not in line`. Also, we need a sample input file and the exact parameters you're passing in... Just an example of something that should work but doesn't. In addition to helping us right now, it helps you in tracking down your own bugs in the future to produce Minimal Reproductions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a much easier way of getting the scores extracted from that string, no regex involved, is to use the `split()` method. That method will split the input string on any whitespace and return an array of the substrings.

```
def getlsuscore(line):
    # Example line: 02:24 LSU 62 - 80 ...
    splitResults = line.split()

    # Index 0 holds the time,
    # Index 1 holds the team name,
    # Index 2 holds the first score (as a string still),
    # Index 3 holds the separating dash,
    # Index 4 holds the second score (as a string still),
    # And further indexes hold everything else
    firstScore  = int(splitResults[2])
    secondScore = int(splitResults[4])
    print(firstScore, secondScore)
    return firstScore
```

Comment: If I try this with 3 as the index, I get "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'". If I try it with 5 as the index, I get "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'EDDLESTONE,BRANDON'". Both as expected.

However, when I try it with 4 I get "IndexError: list index out of range"

Printing the list in the line right before, I get 
`['02:24', 'LSU', '62', '-', '80', 'EDDLESTONE,BRANDON', 'SUB', 'IN.', 'SHORTESS,HENRY', 'SUB', 'IN.', 'ROBINSON', 'III,ELBERT', 'SUB', 'OUT.', 'QUARTERMAN,TIM', 'SUB', 'OUT.']`
as expected. What's going on here?

Comment: @John - Does that surprise you? Index 3 holds the dash, as I mentioned in the comments of the code. What would you expect `int('-')` to return? It's not a valid number of any sort, so it raises an error instead.

Comment: No, it doesn't. but the error when I use 4 as the index does surprise me. I only used 3 and 5 to see if it worked for other parts of the list.

Comment: @John - Hmm... That's odd. Edit your question to have the exact code giving you that exception...

Comment: Yeah, the weird thing is this is in a file that is a couple hundred lines long and I've tried it on a similar one and it only messes up like that towards the end. Editing it momentarily

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
m = re.search('(\\d+)\\s*-\\s*(\\d+)', line)
s1 = int(m.group(1))
s2 = int(m.group(2))
print(s1, s2)
```

This just looks for two numbers separated by a hypen, then decodes them into `s1` and `s2`, after which you can do what you like with them.  In practice, you should check `m` to make sure it isn't `None`, which would indicate a failed search.

Answer (score 0):

Use a group to extract the number instead of resorting to fiddling with the start index of the match:

```
>>> import re
>>> line="02:24 LSU 62 - 80 EDDLESTONE,BRANDON SUB IN. blah blah..."
>>> int(re.search(r' - (\d+)', line).group(1))
80
>>>
```

If you get an error like `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` that means that the line you are working on doesn't have the " - (\d+)" sequence in it. For instance, maybe its an empty line. You can catch the problem with a try/except block. Then you have to decide whether this is a bad error or not. If you are absolutely positive that all lines follow your rules then maybe its a fatal error and you should exit warning the user that data is bad. Or if you are more loosey about the data, ignore it and continue.